# CSS Bundling for rails not watching on M1 mac when using Colima

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, apple-m1, ruby-on-rails-7

## Problem

[Cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) only compiles within a Docker container on Apple M1 macbook at start up of container. Making subsequent changes to the specified watched scss file are not triggering recompiling.
The docker container is being run with [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima).

### Specifics

The set up is using Foreman and procfile to handle the watchers for both cssbundling-rails and also [jsbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails). bin/dev is executed within the docker-compose file. The javascript bundling is watching and re-compliling the application.js as expected.

The Colima context is being set up with the following commands

`colima start --arch x86_64 --cpu 4 --memory 6 --disk`

`docker context use colima`

The following command was run successfully within the docker container: `rails css:install:bootstrap`

The Macbook is running MacOS Monterey Version 12.6

Package.json includes the following scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
```

When making any changes to `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss` nothing is recompiled. Tearing down the docker container and then restarting it causes the css to be recompiled. No failures are listed in terminal.

The following is output from the restarted container

`$ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch`

`$ Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop`

### Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "3.1.3"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlserver as the database for Active Record
gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
#gem "importmap-rails"

gem "tiny_tds"

gem "jsbundling-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

gem "cssbundling-rails"


group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem "faker"
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to MacOS 13 Ventura and enabling "Use Virtualization framework" in Docker Desktop enabled css bundling to work as expected.

A change in the `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss` file causes the watcher to trigger the css to be recompiled.

[Docker's documentation on new virtualization framework](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/#use-rosetta-for-x86amd64-emulation-on-apple-silicon)